# Relating frequency domain to Bandwidth

Tags: frequency

I was just wondering about the frequency domain with regards to bandwidth. I am not sure how to relate the bandwidth of a signal to its frequency. For example, I have a Fourier transformed equation of the form G(f) = rect(Pi*f/1000) + tri(Pi*f/2000). Would the bandwidth be 500/Pi for the rectangular function?

Comment: What do you mean by "wavelength" of a signal? Photons have wavelengths. Signals kind of don't.

Comment: What does this mean: "For a certain frequency it has the same magnitude at its positive and negative end."? What is "it", and what are positive and negative ends? To determine wavelength from frequency, the all important parameter is velocity.

Comment: Sorry I meant Bandwidth. How would I find bandwidth from the frequency spectrum given a signal?

Comment: why does your question still say "wavelength" ?

Comment: @DKNguyen Of course signals have wavelength, related to frequency by \$f\lambda=3\times 10^8\$ in free space

Comment: @Chu The OP referred to the various frequency components of a signal, not just the carrier, so it doesn't make much sense to be talking about wavelength (at least that's how I interpreted the question).